# Why does joining more than 1 subquery create a slowdown?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Right now I'm attempting to do something like so:

```
SELECT salePrice, listPrice, lowestListPrice, lastChange
FROM deals NATURAL JOIN  products

NATURAL JOIN 
(SELECT dealID, MAX(date) as lastChange 
FROM price_history 
GROUP BY dealID) as priceHistory

NATURAL JOIN 
(SELECT productID, MIN(listPrice) as lowestListPrice 
FROM deals 
GROUP BY productID) as listPrices

LIMIT 0, 30
```

Everything has worked fine, until I attempted to add the last join/subquery. I can run both subqueries very quickly, and swapping one for the other it runs fine, but using both together results in a huge slow down.

From the initial research, it sounds like it might be running the 2nd subquery for each row in the result set? Not sure. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The better would to provide the schema, `EXPLAIN` and the task description

Comment: Prior to v5.6.3, derived tables are not indexed: therefore joining two of them together can be very inefficient.

Comment: Have you looked at [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) before and after?